# Can I get soil clay, silt, and sand content from particle size analysis data (hydrometer ans sieve method) in R?

Tags: r, size, textures, particles, soil

I made a particle size analysis on 150 soil samples using the hydrometer and sieve method. For each sample, I have a table with particle diameter (d) and percent passing (%P), which indicates the sample's amount consisting of particles smaller than diameter X :
[Data table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v6V2T.png)

I can make a particle size curve from this table :
[Particle size curve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wrksw.png)

From this curve, I can get the percent passing at 50µm and 2µm to determine the soil clay (<2µm), silt (between 2µm and 50µm), and sand (>50µm) content.

It takes a lot of time to do that with 150 samples, so I want a code in R to get soil clay, silt, and sand content from the data in the table (d and %P).

I read about the soil texture wizard in R, but it doesn't seem like it would help me solve my problem.

Thanks!

Comment: Hi Thomas, could you provide some sample data? I suspect this would be relatively easy to do with dplyr.

Comment: Also an example of the expected output as well.

Comment: Hi Dave, the link "Data table" in my question is an example for the sample MLS-1, and the link "Particle size curve" is made from "Data table".

Comment: Then, I can get the percent passing at 50µm and 2µm from the curve. Percent passing at 2µm represents clay content, percent passing at 50µm represents silt + clay content, and sand content is calculated by 100% - percent passing at 50µm. For the sample MLS-1, %P at 2µm  is 2% and %P at 50µm is 17.5%. So, the expected output is clay=2%; silt=15.5% (17.5% - 2%); sand=82.5% (100% - 17.5%).

Comment: In short, my goal is to obtain clay, silt, and sand percentage from the initial "Data table" without having to do the particle size curve in Excel for each of my 150 soil samples.